# yowsup registration error with --cc or C

Tags: python, yowsup

*I am using this command to register my device*

```
yowsup-cli registration -d -E android -m 404 -n 24 -r sms -C +91 -p +9189********
```

*this is the version of yowsup2.*

```
yowsup-cli v2.0.15 
yowsup v2.5.2
```

**and getting**

```
INFO:yowsup.common.http.warequest:
b'{"status":"fail","reason":"bad_param","param":"cc"}\n' 
param: b'cc' 
status: b'fail' 
reason: b'bad_param'
```

any idea guys what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue with the phone number and country code you have provided.

```
$ yowsup-cli registration --help
```

shows that ,

> -p PHONE, --phone PHONE
>                           Your full phone number including the country code you
>                           defined in 'cc', without preceeding '+' or '00'

So the command should have been,

```
yowsup-cli registration -d -E android -m 404 -n 24 -r sms -C 91 -p 9189********
```